# Meaning of "are they worth it? It was a secret showing of badges, of scars"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

This passage is from *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

> They sat in the high seats at the back of the bus, and Poppy sank into her
> book. Up at the front sat a European woman in her forties, dressed in a satin
> suit and high-heeled shoes as if for an outing. Elizabeth could not work out
> her relationship to the two men she appeared to be with, who were
> conversing in the seat opposite. As the bus swung round into Russell Street,
> one of the men tossed a piece of screwed-up paper on to the high shelf of
> the woman’s breasts. She looked down very slowly, and very slowly she
> picked the rubbish off her bosom; she was smiling with humiliation.
> Elizabeth stood up to walk down the bus to the door, with Poppy stumbling
> after her, still reading. The woman looked up at Elizabeth as she passed.
> They held eyes. The woman made the grimace, and Elizabeth returned it:
> corners of the mouth go down, head tilts to one side, shoulders come up in a
> shrug: ***are they worth it*? It was a secret showing of badges, of scars**. Had
> Poppy seen? It would contaminate her. But Poppy was finishing a chapter.
> She kept a grip on Elizabeth’s sleeve and forged down the page with her
> eyes. Her feet were braced well apart on the jolting floor.

Does "**they**" in the sentence "***are they worth it*? It was a secret showing of badges, of scars**" refer to "two men", and does the whole sentence mean "are that two men worth it that the woman demean herself? and with grimacing Elizabeth and that woman were showing secretly their defeats and victories in their relationship with men"?

I asked this question in Literature Stack Exchange but nobody answered and I asked it in this forum.

Comment: This looks to me like *Don't waste a bullet on him, **he's not worth it*** in crime / western movies (the woman wonders whether it's worth speaking up / making a fuss about the fact that the men are being disrespectful to her). But this is really a matter of *literary interpretation*, not some clear-cut issue of exact intended meaning as reflected by precise use of language.

Comment: It probably refers to all men in general, but it's not clear enough what the author had in mind

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That looks like a good understanding and analysis of that part of the text.

Note that the bold part isn't a sentence. "Are they worth it?" is like a quote, but of thoughts, not words. It is the thought of Elizabeth, or perhaps the understanding that Elizabeth has of what the woman is thinking.  "It was ..." is a separate sentence, and comes not from Elizabeth, but from the narrator.